# Event scheduler in mysql 5.0

Tags: mysql

i want to schedule export mysql table to csv and import to mysql on another server using event scheduler option . the two server is in different version 5.0 and 5.1 . i realize that event schedule option is not available in mysql 5.0 . is there any mysql script to do this ?

Comment: Although MySQL supports event scheduling, you probably want to do this with something like `cron` instead. If you're running MySQL 5.0 that's an extremely historical version, perhaps over ten years old. The current version is 5.7.

Comment: yes i think so ,there might be no way beside cron . thank you